# JQuery: Fix Div including re-sizing window

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, resize, fixed

Hi I'm working on a fixed / pinned Div also after re-sizing the Browser Window. To fix the Div is no problem but I'm not able to auto resize the width with jquery. My current code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        function fixDiv() {
            var $cache = $('.pin');
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
                $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '10px', width: $('.pin-wrapper').width()});
           else
                $cache.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto', width: $('.pin-wrapper').width()});
        }
        $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
        fixDiv();
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        fixDiv();
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        fixDiv();
    });
</script>
```

The Html looks like this:

```
<div class="grid-12 parent"> <!-- Kolos 12.02.2014 -->
        <div class="pin-wrapper">
                <div id="header" class="main-menu-container grid-12 hide-mobile pin"></div></div></div>
```

thanks for any help
Cheers, Carol

Comment: You are calling fixDiv() so many times. `$(window).on('load resize scroll', fixDiv);` would be enough. Now regarding your issue, you should replicate it on jsFiddle. BTW `'width': $('.header')` doesn't make sense and your selector `.header` looks wrong, etc...

Comment: @A. Wolff, thanks for you reply. It is working now.

Comment: Please put it into answer and mark as resolved. Have a nice day both of you :)

Comment: @jPO I'm really not sure how OP fixed his issue  EDIT: i see, scoping issue for fixDiv() method

Comment: I believe he put +"px" to his code, but he should answer it himself and then mark his code as answered, because it might be helpful for others. Only therefore

Comment: sorry your right. it's still not fixed. after adding all in one line ('load resize scroll') the div is no more fixed. the line with the .header I changed.

Comment: @AtelierBasel Please provide a jsFiddle with all (and only) relevant code

Comment: If I run your code without the `load` event, it works. Look in the jsFiddle in my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing scoping issue, `fixDiv()` method being declared inside onload handler. You could use instead:

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('.pin');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '10px',
        width: $('.pin-wrapper').width()
    });
    else $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 0,
        'width': $('#header').width()
    });
}
$(window).on('load resize scroll', fixDiv);
```

But in your posted HTML markup, it appears than there is no element with class `header`, looks like you are targeting element with ID `header`. But then, `#header` is the same element as `$cache`, quite confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry but after this change the div is no more fixed.

Comment: @AtelierBasel error in console? Anyway, if you want relevant help, we need to see all your relevant code. What about a jsFiddle?!

Comment: I don't see `'width': $('.header')` no where in his code?

Comment: @Andrei Question was edited, see revision's history. Then which code OP is using becomes unclear...

Comment: Oh, ok, you are right. Still, in the jsFiddle I created with the OP code and removing the `load` altogether, the code works.

Comment: ok, you was absolutely right. your code is working fine. I had JQuery version problem. After updating to the current Version it's working perfekt. Thanks for all, Carol

Answer (score 0):

As A. Wolff mentioned, you shouldn't add your events in the `load` function. Because you were doing that, your scroll event was not fired.

You actually don't need `load` at all as can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uwkc9/3/

If you `scroll` or `resize` you will see that both work.

Also, from practice, I recommend separating your `scroll` and `resize` events to use a separate function. It will be easier to maintain in the feature.